# Error in view pager , showing same data in all tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using this library: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

I am using View Pager fragment to display timetable of my college in different tabs as from Monday to Friday.

My View Pager is in a fragment when opens when a item is clicked in list of NavDrawer. So I get data from database(sql) and create 5 List<> and get their corresponding data and at the time fragment is loaded as:

Error that I am getting is that when I open the fragment, I get timetable of friday in all tabs.

FragmentClass:

```
public class MaterialVPFrag extends Fragment {
private MaterialViewPager mViewPager;
List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_m;
List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_t;
List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_w;
List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_th;
List<Model_Daywise> todayslist_fr;

public static MaterialVPFrag newInstance() {
    return new MaterialVPFrag();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mvp_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    todayslist_m = new MTWTHgetset(getActivity(), "monday").getAllCredentials();
    todayslist_t = new MTWTHgetset(getActivity(), "tuesday").getAllCredentials();
    todayslist_w = new MTWTHgetset(getActivity(), "wednesday").getAllCredentials();
    todayslist_th = new MTWTHgetset(getActivity(), "thursday").getAllCredentials();
    todayslist_fr = new MTWTHgetset(getActivity(), "friday").getAllCredentials();
    mViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);
    mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d("c0", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_t);
                case 1:
                    Log.d("c1", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_t);
                case 2:
                    Log.d("c2", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_w);
                case 3:
                    Log.d("c3", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_th);
                case 4:
                    Log.d("c4", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_fr);
                default:
                    Log.d("cdef", "");
                    return new RecyclerViewFragment(todayslist_m);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Monday";
                case 1:
                    return "Tuesday";
                case 2:
                    return "Wednesday";
                case 3:
                    return "Thursday";
                case 4:
                    return "Friday";
            }
            return "";
        }
    });
    mViewPager.setMaterialViewPagerListener(new MaterialViewPager.Listener() {
        @Override
        public HeaderDesign getHeaderDesign(int page) {
            switch (page) {
                case 0:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.green,
                            "https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg");
                case 1:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.blue,
                            "http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg");
                case 2:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.cyan,
                            "http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg");
                case 3:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.red,
                            "http://www.tothemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/original.jpg");
            }

            //execute others actions if needed (ex : modify your header logo)

            return null;
        }
    });

    mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount()); //it works without it don't know why!
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(mViewPager.getViewPager());

    View logo = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_white);
    if (logo != null)
        logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.notifyHeaderChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes, the title is clickable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

}
}
```

RecyclerViewFragment.java

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
List<Model_Daywise> list;

public RecyclerViewFragment() {
}

public RecyclerViewFragment(List<Model_Daywise> lis) {
    list = lis;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter_Daywise(list, getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);
}
}
```

CardAdapter_Daywise.java

```
public class CardAdapter_Daywise extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter_Daywise.CardViewHolderDaywise> {
private static List<Model_Daywise> cardList;
private Context context = null;

public CardAdapter_Daywise(List<Model_Daywise> list, Context context) {
    this.cardList = list;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public CardViewHolderDaywise onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout_daywise, viewGroup, false);
    return (new CardViewHolderDaywise(itemView));

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CardAdapter_Daywise.CardViewHolderDaywise cardViewHolder, int i) {
    final Model_Daywise cl = cardList.get(i);
    cardViewHolder.subname.setText(cl.getSubname());
    cardViewHolder.subcode.setText(cl.getSubcode());
    cardViewHolder.slot.setText(cl.getSubslot());
    cardViewHolder.timings.setText(cl.getSubtimings());
    cardViewHolder.teacher.setText(cl.getSubteacher());
    cardViewHolder.venue.setText(cl.getVenue());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}


public class CardViewHolderDaywise extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView subname, subcode, slot, venue, teacher, timings;

    public CardViewHolderDaywise(View v) {
        super(v);
        subname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subject_name_daywise);
        subcode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub_code_daywise);
        slot = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.slot_daywise);
        venue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_daywise);
        teacher = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_daywise);
        timings = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timings_daywise);
    }


  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RecyclerViewFragment` you've declared the `list` field as static which means that every `RecyclerViewFragment` instance will share the data that was **last** put in it.

For example, if you first show the `RecyclerViewFragment` for monday it will load the `todayslist_m` list in the 'list' reference. But, the ViewPager will also build the fragment for the next page(tuesday in your case) to improve performance which means a new `RecyclerViewFragment` will be created, this time the static `list` reference pointing to todayslist_m. This way you'll end up having the `RecyclerViewFragment` for both monday and tuesday pointing the same list of data(the last one set on the `RecyclerViewFragment`).

The solution is to make the `list` reference in `RecyclerViewFragment` to **not** be static and rethink your approach if you used static as a mean to reference the `list` from outside the `RecyclerViewFragment` fragment.

Comment: Hey, I don't what's the problem now, but now I am getting Friday's timetable in all tabs, I have edited the question!

Comment: Earlier I was using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager(), so it was crashing at                                                                                                                                    mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount()); so I removed that line , now that I am using getChild..  , and I have that line , It's showing Friday in all.

Comment: I tried logging the getItem() , it's not getting called , when I change tabs.

Comment: @NikhilVerma In RecyclerViewFragment also make mAdapter to not be static.

Comment: Yeah I spotted that, and did that just before you commented. Thank you, now its working fine.